# How to rename similarly-named variables in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have recreated a situation at basic level in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Y5FN/74/. I have a few variables that end with a number:

```
var var1;
var var2;
var var3;
```

How can I use these variables in a way where I'm iterating through them in a `for` statement by changing the number at the end of the variables name? Is it even possible to do so? The goal would to be to change each variable's value to 3. Here are some ways I tried to do it:

```
var(1), var[2], var+'3'
```

Comment: window['var'+i], although it seems like an odd thing to need to do. What are you attempting to do at a higher level?

Comment: Oh man i dont even know how to start to explain that lol but am I applying it wrong here http://jsfiddle.net/5Y5FN/75/

Comment: The problem is that unless those variables are global, you can't access them the way you want to (as far as I know). It might be easier to store them in a simple object as key:value pairs like `var items = { var1 : 1}` so that you can access them by `items['var' + i]`

Comment: instead of working with multiple variables, use an array of values in a single variable, then you can access each member of the array using its index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your variables so they are a Javascript array instead of named variables as is. The result is that you can then iterate over them.

So var1,2,3 will become varArray[1], varArray[2], varArray[3] etc.

Comment: except 'var' is a reserved word, so you can't name your array like that.

Comment: @Aleuck : Yes, to quick of a post :) Corrected it to a working variable :)

Answer (score 0):

If your `var1`, `var2` etc variables are inside a function, there's nothing you can do. But if these variables are declared in the top level scope, they will be set as atributes on the global object (`window`, in the browser).

If that's the case (variables defined in the top-level object, or in some other object if you might, but not as function-scoped variables), you could do something like:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    window['var' + i] = 'some value';
}
```